# How can I export static class methods without exporting the whole class

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

I am creating a node package to handle cookies. What is the best way to export static class methods from the class below?

```
export default class Cookies {
    static get (name) {...}
    static set (...) {...}
    static remove (...) {...}
}
```

And is it then possible to import them like this, so people don't have to import the remove method if they don't need it?

`import { get, set } from "Cookies"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since they are static methods, they are basically just properties on the class object. Since that is the case, you can just export them one by one:

```
export default class Cookies {
    static get (name) {...}
    static set (...) {...}
    static remove (...) {...}
}

export const get = Cookies.get;
export const set = Cookies.set;
export const remove = Cookies.remove;
```

Comment: Couldn't you export all in 1 export statement with braces?

Comment: You could, but then you couldn't import them separately AFAIK.

Comment: Hi @torazaburo I wasn't aware of that. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: If you or the OP wants to use a single export statement, remove the `export` keyword from the `export const` statements, then write `export {get, set, remove};`. A single one of those could then imported with `import {get} from './cookies';`. There is no way to combine everything into a single export statement; that would require something like `export {Cookies.get as get};` which is invalid syntax.